# Remove letter from a string access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a string sStr that contains letters and numbers.I'm trying to remove letters from a string.

For eg: sStr= "P441"  or sometimes sStr="BK471" .

I tried using 
`Right(sStr,3)` and `split`

which gives me 441. since the string sStr may contain 2 letters ("BK471") sometimes,  how do i remove letters in vba .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each character in the string checking if it `IsNumeric`

```
Dim x as integer
Dim sCleanedStr As String
For x = 1 to Len(sStr)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(sStr, x, 1)) then sCleanedStr = sCleanedStr & Mid(sStr, x, 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions to remove any letters. For this, you need to include the Regex library in your macro (Go to Tools -> References, then search and select the regular expressions library)

```
Sub test()

sStr = "abc123"
Dim regEx As New RegExp
With regEx
    .Pattern = "[a-z]+"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With
sStr = regEx.Replace(sStr, "")
MsgBox (sStr)

End Sub
```

The above code will replace any letter from anywhere in the word.